# Check if youtube video ended in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I create google extension for Youtube. And i want to check if video is ended.

I check it by current and duration time, but Youtube sometime don't update current time and i can't check it

```
let current = document.querySelector('span.ytp-time-current').textContent;
let duration = document.querySelector('span.ytp-time-duration').textContent;
if (current == duration) {
    console.log('Video is ended');
}
```

Comment: Simply subscribe to the standard [DOM event `'ended'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) on the `<video>` element?

Comment: It's wotk! Thanks